# Why can I not login after updating to macOS 13.3?

Tags: macos, software-update, external-disk, ventura

After updating to macOS 13.3, I cannot login. My username/password seems to be accepted, but then I get a blank screen (with wallpaper) with a circular spinner. My home directory is on an external drive, but the correct path is in my account config and has been working perfectly prior to the 13.3 update. What is happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why would you put the home directory on an external drive?  This is likely the issue because the mount is probably not the same mount point as before.  Move your home directory back to where it’s supposed to be.

Comment: Because the home directory is "supposed to be" at the path defined in the user account, which can absolutely be on an external drive, or even on a network share. This is basic, and has always worked.

Comment: Go to System Settings / Users & Groups, right-click on a user account, and pick Advanced Options. Note that you can choose a different location for the home directory, IOW this is a supported feature.

Comment: Except when the volume isn’t unmounted correctly and the new mount point become `/Volumes/Users 2` while `/Volumes/Users` still exists.  You’d be better off with a symlink to the external drive.

Comment: Or when the volume name has been changed, or when the external drive has been reformatted, or when the computer is off -- or when the symlink doesn't work properly for a particular process. The point is, you're better off doing it the right way.

Comment: Thanks for coming back despite the downvotes and updating both the question and the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would appear that there is a system-level permission change in 13.3 that requires an update to the account's Apple ID settings in order to allow the system to access external drives. If the home directory is on an external drive, this creates a catch-22 situation.

[This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/124fods/warning_133_breaks_setups_where_home_directories/je9yt8u/) describes a workaround. The short version is: Disable SIP, login to each user account with a home directory on an external drive and update the Apple ID settings, then re-enable SIP. This issue may affect network homes as well; not confirmed.

Comment: A little more info on the underlying issue:
https://www.macworld.com/article/1683099/macos-ventura-13-3-home-directory-bug-system-integrity-protection.html

It's the "Allow accessories to connect" privilege configuration under "Privacy & Security" in System Settings. So this issue probably doesn't affect network home directories, only those on locally connected accessories.

Comment: The 'more info' needs to be here, with links to references. Forcing users to offsite links [which may or may not be here forever] just breaks the SE system [that's why all the downvotes]. Quote, or précis, with citation.

Comment: First, the "more info" is not required for the fix, it's extra. Second, how much more info do you need than the exact location of the setting in question? Third, the downvotes were cast prior to my update of an hour ago, which substantially altered the content of the original answer, which didn't contain sufficient information (iow totally unrelated to the "more info" comment).

Comment: I didn't get flagged for the updated answer, only the comment. I'll pull my own DV after the added info.